# After upgrading to mavericks, Synergy no longer works

Tags: synergy

Followed [these workarounds](http://synergy-foss.org/blog/mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks-support/) exactly, but still get the following error. Synergy worked fine before

```
ERROR: cannot read configuration "/var/folders/...": read error: line 38: unknown screen name in switchToScreen
synergys: no configuration available
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [version of Synergy available](http://synergy-project.org/download/) for OS X 10.9.